# Improving performance of complex PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to shorten the time for this query. Someone told me about `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, but I have no idea how to interpret the results and what fixes to make. Any suggestions? Note that I'm using a third party's database (cartoDB), so I don't think I have the option to create indexes.

Here's the query. The two tables in this are about 40 rows and about 32,000 rows.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT
  id, identifier,
  CASE
    WHEN dist <  8046. THEN 1
    WHEN dist <  16093. THEN 2
    WHEN dist < 40233. THEN 3
WHEN dist < 80467. THEN 4
WHEN dist < 160934. THEN 5
    ELSE 6
  END AS grp,
  count(*)
FROM (
    SELECT s.id, s.identifier, ST_Distance_Sphere(s.the_geom, c.the_geom) AS dist
    FROM full_data_for_testing_deid_2 c, demo_locations_table s) AS loc_dist
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Here is the response to the `EXECUTE ANALYZE`:

```
{
  "fields" : {
    "QUERY PLAN" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  },
  "rows" : [
    {
      "QUERY PLAN" : "GroupAggregate  (cost=373146.40..651612.12 rows=1058805 width=128) (actual time=34120.054..37536.893 rows=197 loops=1)"
    },
    {
      "QUERY PLAN" : "  ->  Sort  (cost=373146.40..373675.81 rows=1058805 width=128) (actual time=34120.000..36504.439 rows=1058805 loops=1)"
    },
    {
      "QUERY PLAN" : "        Sort Key: s.id, s.identifier, (CASE WHEN (_st_distance(geography(s.the_geom), geography(c.the_geom), 0::double precision, false) < 8046::double precision) THEN 1 WHEN (_st_distance(geography(s.the_geom), geography(c.the_geom), 0::double precision, false) < 16093::double precision) THEN 2 WHEN (_st_distance(geography(s.the_geom), geography(c.the_geom), 0::double precision, false) < 40233::double precision) THEN 3 WHEN (_st_distance(geography(s.the_geom), geography(c.the_geom), 0::double precision, false) < 80467::double precision) THEN 4 WHEN (_st_distance(geography(s.the_geom), geography(c.the_geom), 0::double precision, false) < 160934::double precision) THEN 5 ELSE 6 END)"
    },
    {
      "QUERY PLAN" : "        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 35200kB"
    },
    {
      "QUERY PLAN" : "        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..283194.48 rows=1058805 width=128) (actual time=0.688..13487.097 rows=1058805 loops=1)"
    },
    {
      "QUERY PLAN" : "              ->  Seq Scan on full_data_for_testing_deid_2 c  (cost=0.00..6845.26 rows=32085 width=32) (actual time=0.006..130.054 rows=32085 loops=1)"
    },
    {
      "QUERY PLAN" : "              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.13 rows=33 width=96) (actual time=0.001..0.028 rows=33 loops=32085)"
    },
    {
      "QUERY PLAN" : "                    ->  Seq Scan on demo_locations_table s  (cost=0.00..1.10 rows=33 width=96) (actual time=0.003..0.034 rows=33 loops=1)"
    },
    {
      "QUERY PLAN" : "Total runtime: 37569.205 ms"
    }
  ],
  "time" : 37.574,
  "total_rows" : 9
}
```

Comment: What's slowing down your query is likely the inner select statement. Can't you rework your query to avoid using it?

Comment: I'm pretty new to PostgreSQL and mySQL for that matter, so I'm not quite sure how I'd go about doing that.

Comment: I'm not sure what indexes are on the table currently. I don't know if cartodb(where this service is hosted) adds indexes or not.

Comment: I highly doubt indexes would help; you are calculating 1.3 million distances... over a sphere.

Comment: please show results of `show create table full_data_for_testing_deid_2` and the other one too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in cartesian product here : 
    SELECT s.id, s.identifier, ST_Distance_Sphere(s.the_geom, c.the_geom) AS dist 
    FROM full_data_for_testing_deid_2 c, demo_locations_table s

following by nested loop.
I dont think you wanted to do cartesian here. 
you can easily cut off some unnecessary loops by more specific JOIN ON.
The distance between two points is commutative function. 
So just add the following condition to it like : c.pk > s.pk depending on your needs (no info about schema design)